# Is it safe to write code like this to handle errors and parse JSON data when reading a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I saved some JSON string in a file, and want to write a function to simplify the reading and parsing for other code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function readObject(callback) {
  fs.readFile('./data.json', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    else callback(null, JSON.parse(content));
  });
}
```

And I think it might be a little simpler:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function readObject(callback) {
  fs.readFile('./data.json', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
    callback(err, content && JSON.parse(content));
  });
}
```

So I can write just one line to handle the callback.

Is this way safe and good?

Comment: FYI `JSON.parse` can throw, taking down your whole application

Comment: You can use `require` to load a json file too which will convert to javascript object `try{ var data = require("./data.json") } catch (e){//error}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise for such operations. It's actually better way than using the callbacks. If you are using ECMAScript6, it's inbuilt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Otherwise you can use any promise library like bluebird etc.